# How to sideload windows cordova app without running powershell script

Tags: windows, cordova, powershell, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova

I have a successful windows build for a Cordova app and can deploy to my machine by running the Add-AppDevPackages PowerShell script. I want users to be able to install the app without having to run the script. I.e. They can just download the app and click the file to install on their device, which is how we are delivering the iOS and Android versions.

My thought process was 1) can I create a .msi file setup wizard that will run the PowerShell script once the file is opened?

or

2) Do I need a signing certificate similar to how apple's certs work

This is an internal app, so there is no need for it to go on the app store.